# Docker The source path has too many colons

Tags: docker

I have run on the Windows command prompt (I have the Linux subsystem for Windows installed):

```
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend_web_architecture/github_repos/data-privacy-api/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysq"l -v C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend_web_architecture/github_repos/data-privacy-api/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

This throws:

```
The source path "/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend_web_architecture/github_repos/data-privacy-api/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysql -v C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend_web_architecture/github_repos/data-privacy-api/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
too many colons.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I though the colon at e.g. `db_records:/var` is necessary? What would I need to fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Btuman Just got this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @datasciencelearner = I don't see a sudo in front of the docker run command, so I take it your running this on the windows commandline. Have you tried to wrap the path arguments in quotes?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the output

A volume mapping is specified as:

- `{locationOnHost}:{locationInsideContainer}`

Since the volume you're mapping contains a colon (C:...) - docker will take this as the seperator in the mapping

You can use WSL's `wslpath` to convert this to a *nix safe path e.g.

`wslpath -a 'C:\a\b\ccc\'`

results in

`/mnt/c/a/b/ccc/`

Comment: this almost worked for me, but I had to use `/c/path/to/folder`, as highlighted in this answer and it's comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750767/884842