# Error while running Jenkins in Docker when I try to build a Job

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to running a Jenkins into a Docker using a Docker compose and when i try to build a job Jenkins shows me the next error:

```
Salida de consola
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3260)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1300(FilePath.java:211)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1251)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1247)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1243)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1200)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1880)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is Docker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  master:
    build: .
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
 
volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

And this is my Docker file:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
 
USER SYSTEM
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y maven
 
USER jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like your user has insufficient permissions here `/C:\......\MOM\JSFiles`, check the folders permissions. From your log >  `AccessDeniedException`

Comment: Please add your Jenkins Pipeline script (Jenkinsfile) or your job configuration with the exact executed commands. It looks like your build job is trying to write to a location (inside your container) where you do not have write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

User `jenkins` in your container does not have access to folder `C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles` on your host. Given your `docker-compose.yml`  it's probably caused by either:

- This directory does not exists in your container (as per the volume you are mounting), you may try to add

```
    volumes:
       - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
       - /c/Users/cpaez/Documents/Automation/MOM/JSFiles:/c/Users/cpaez/Documents/Automation/MOM/JSFiles
```

- Ensure this folder has enough permission for `jenkins` user in your container to write this directory (your container will run as this user as per the `USER jenkins` instruction)

Comment: Hi , I changed my docker compose :
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles:C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles  And this is the error that it is showing me now when i executed: docker-compose up -d
Creating mom_master_1 ... error

ERROR: for mom_master_1  Cannot create container for service master: Mount denied:
The source path "\\Users\\cpaez\\Documents\\Automation\\MOM\\JSFiles:C:\\Users\\cpaez\\Documents\\Automation\\MOM\\JSFiles:rw"       
too many colons

  Can you help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: On Windows specifying paths for Compose is a bit different than on plain Linux (need to use `/` and not `\` ), I updated my answer

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334021/volume-binding-using-docker-compose-on-windows to setup Docker Compose volumes on WIndows

Comment: Hi,thank you,  now i can access but this error appears :
Started by user Carolina
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles
[JSFiles] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7772105530923733597.sh
+ ./run.sh
/tmp/jenkins7772105530923733597.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins7772105530923733597.sh: ./run.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Great, happy to help :) Your initial issue seems to be solved, this seems unrelated to your first issue, it seems you are trying to use `run.sh` script during your build but the file is not found. Maybe ask another question or edit this one with your Jenkins build steps